# Distributed Build Icecream failed Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: c++, distcc

We are using icecream [github](https://github.com/icecc/icecream): distributed build (like distcc) for compiling our c++ code among several machines.

However, we frequently encounter exceptions:

```
ICECC[16186] 18:57:54: write of source chunk to host 192.168.168.82
ICECC[16186] 18:57:54: failed  Resource temporarily unavailable
ICECC[16186] 18:57:54: got exception 15 (192.168.168.82)
```

After failing to trying to pass jobs to all the machines, local machine is forced to compile this job itself.

Does anyone try icc before and know how to solve this issue (maybe in the source code)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

How many tasks do you allow `make` to distribute? We usually saw that kind of behaviour if we did `make -j`, flooding the scheduler with jobs and overstrain it.

If you do the same, try calling `make -j$NUM_CORES_IN_NETWORK`.